# How to choose a 50 Ohm RF attenuator for radio, bluetooth and wifi power measurements

Tags: power, rf, power-electronics, power-engineering, microwave

I have built a power meter with [AD8318](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8318.pdf), a chip which contains a logarithmic amplifier, often used for power measurements.

I have read its datasheet and it is written that the maximum input power is equal to 12 dBm.

[image]

I do not know exactly which kind of measures I can do with this limits, but it correspondes to 15.85mW, which I think is quite low for many applications. Precisely, I wanted to use it to measure power from wifi networks, bluetooth, mobile network and radio stations.

So I need some advices about if it is necessary to buy a RF attenuator to put between the antenna and the power meter (with 50 Ohm SMA coaxial cable) and how many dB of attenuation I need for these applications. Since I am not an expert of rf attenuators, if you think I should consider other parameters for choosing an attenuator, tell me!

Comment: Use a Directional Coupler DC-n to sample the output power below 12dBm after you estimate your design spec for min max input.  DC's come in all manner of cost and performance ranges. Stripline being the cheapest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical P_EIRP of standard wifi/ble/zigbee networks is in the range of 0dBm to 10dBm. This is the equivalent output power of an isotropic ratiator.

If you have a distance of (only) 1m in between a wifi/ble/zigbee sender and your receiving meter, the attenuation of air will be around -40dB at 2.4GHz.

Given that you have mostly isotropic radiators with little antenna gain, your receiving power will be about max. -30dBm at 1m distance to the wifi/ble/zigbee sender.

So you can safely do wireless measurements with your power meter without worrying about the power limit. But you should not wire the power meter directly to a  wifi/ble/zigbee source without attenuator.